# Knockout - Url routing - params

Tags: url, knockout.js, url-parameters

At this time I am developing site using Knockout.js. I am wondering how can I set up effectively some params to url? For example, if I have a ajax loading table I would like to set up the page number and sorting?

I have found some libs like sammy.js but it seems pretty old.

Thanks

Comment: you might want to share your proofs of concept, what have you found so far, what library are you considering, try some out yourself, put the code samples here, and then there could be a valuable discussion. You just can't come here with an attitude of 'please supply me with a working solution for my request' ..

Comment: thanks for your reply. I found many libraries, but most of them wasn't updated for many years. I am not looking for working solutions. I am looking for ideas how to do this. There is a possibility that somebody knows some library wich I didn't found or knows same other way how do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them as url params, you're going to want a [router](https://github.com/Profiscience/knockout-contrib/tree/master/packages/router). If you want them in the querystring, you can make/use a [querystring abstraction](https://github.com/Profiscience/knockout-contrib/tree/master/packages/query).

This has been a shameless plug. Thanks for listening. If you decide to use either of these packages, I'm available for help on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/Profiscience/ko-component-router).